# Blurring Image with convolution matrices - artifacts (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, image-processing, pixel, convolution, blur

I'm trying to do some image processing with Haskell (using JuicyPixels). I've done this function that apply Gaussian Blur to the image and there's some strange artifacts in processed image:

```
blur :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8 
blur img@Image {..} = generateImage blurrer imageWidth imageHeight
       where blurrer x y | x >= (imageWidth - offset) || x < offset
                          || y >= (imageHeight - offset) || y < offset = whitePx
                         | otherwise = do
                let applyKernel i j p | j >= matrixLength = applyKernel (i + 1) 0 p
                                      | i >= matrixLength = p 
                                      | otherwise = do 
                                         let outPixel = pxMultNum 
                                                         (pixelAt img (x + j - offset) (y + i - offset)) 
                                                         (gblurMatrix !! i !! j)
                                         applyKernel i (j+1) (outPixel `pxPlus` p)
                applyKernel 0 0 zeroPx
             gblurMatrix = [[1  / 255, 4  / 255,  6 / 255,  4 / 255, 1 / 255],
                            [4  / 255, 16 / 255, 24 / 255, 16 / 255, 4 / 255],
                            [6  / 255, 24 / 255, 36 / 255, 24 / 255, 6 / 255],
                            [4  / 255, 16 / 255, 24 / 255, 16 / 255, 4 / 255],
                            [1  / 255, 4  / 255,  6 / 255,  4 / 255, 1 / 255]]
             matrixLength = length gblurMatrix
             offset = matrixLength `div` 2

whitePx = PixelRGBA8 255 255 255 255
zeroPx = PixelRGBA8 0 0 0 255

pxPlus :: PixelRGBA8 -> PixelRGBA8 -> PixelRGBA8 
pxPlus (PixelRGBA8 r1 g1 b1 a1) (PixelRGBA8 r2 g2 b2 a2) = PixelRGBA8 (s r1 r2) (s g1 g2) (s b1 b2) 255
  where s p1 p2 | p1 + p2 > 255 = 255
                | p1 + p2 < 0 = 0
                | otherwise = p1 + p2

pxMultNum :: PixelRGBA8 -> Double -> PixelRGBA8
pxMultNum (PixelRGBA8 r g b a) q = PixelRGBA8 (m r) (m g) (m b) (m a)
  where m px = pxify $ fromIntegral px * q -- pxify is just synonym to function rounding a = (floor (a + 0.5))
```

Here are input image
[image: input image]
and output image
[image: output image]

It looks like blueish areas are a bit less with `1/256` coefficient in Gaussian Blur Matrix, but how to get rid of them at all?

FIX: I guess it's because of `Pixel8` type 0-255 and Int, but I fixed whole thing just by changing `36` in the kernel center to `35`, so sum of matrix coefficients is (I believe) 255/255 = 1.

Comment: Do your kernel values sum up to 1? Do you perform the computations in a floating-point type? The effect looks like overflow, but only in the red channel.

Comment: I know that it looks like overflow and it seems to be on the close to white areas but as you  can see in `pxPlus` function I've tried to fix overflow issues

Comment: I’m trying to decode the computations made. I have never tried to read Haskell before, this is quite different. In any case it looks like you accumulate the sum in an 8-bit integer. This means that every product of a pixel and the corresponding kernel element is rounded before addition (or it is equivalent to that). Instead, do the accumulation in a floating-point type, and then cast to integer (with clamping) before assigning into the output image.

Comment: I fixed it changing 36 to 35 coefficient in the middle so they're all sum up to 1 I guess in Int 0-255 Pixel type

Comment: Your `p1 + p2 > 255` condition in `pxPlus` is never true. Same for `p1 + p2 < 0`. Addition on `Word8` is mod 256. What is `pxMultNum`?

Comment: @DanielWagner oh, it actually does make sense, thank you!

Comment: Okay, that reply makes me think this was the source of your problem, so I've promoted that comment to an answer.

Comment: What's the point of bothering with 8-bit channels if you're going to ruin your performance anyway with _list lookups_ into a list-matrix of double-precision floats? Might as well just use floating-point pixels all the way, then it's much easier to get normalisation right and you don't need to worry about overflow until the end...

Comment: Also: that's not really a Gaussian blur. For a Gaussian blur it's much more efficient to use the fact that it's _separable_, i.e. that you can first blur only in the x-direction (using a 1D kernel) and then only in the y-direction, and get the same result as blurring once with a 2D kernel.

Comment: @leftaroundabout but how do I convert `PixelRGBA8` to `PixelRGBF` and backwards?

Comment: @Vadim doesn't `promotePixel` / [`promoteImage`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#v:promoteImage) do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

```
| p1 + p2 > 255 = 255
| p1 + p2 < 0 = 0
```

to protect against overflow, but these conditions are never true. `Word8` values are *always* between `0` and `255`. A correct way to check for overflow looks like this:

```
| p1 + p2 < p1 = 255
```

But better would be to avoid overflow in the first place. I note that your blur matrix's coefficients add up to `256/255`. Perhaps you could start by fixing that.

Comment: Any suggestions how to store negative numbers in pixels? I mean I need to iteratively sum RGB pixels values and eventually I must get valid ones, but kernels often have negative coefficients and as you said `Word8` is 0-255. So how to change my code to work with such kernels? I think I may add some `acc`s but I don't know how to left my code clean and not overloaded.

Comment: @Vadim Convert to `PixelRGBF`, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

It is great that you are learning image processing in Haskell, but there are too many problems in your implementation and I don't want others to be learning from it. I'll first go through the problems and then provide a better solution for doing Gaussian blur in Haskell.

Issue with integer overflow that was already identified in the other answer by @Daniel Wagner is definitely the problem. However I would have solved it by changing the type of `pxPlus` instead:

```hs
pxPlus :: PixelRGBF -> PixelRGBF -> PixelRGBF
```

but that's besides the point.

Much bigger problem in the original implementation is the performance, it is simply atrocious. Just to give you an idea, implementation in the question takes ~16 sec on my laptop, while the solution I provide towards the bottom takes 0.007 sec

Here are just some of the main reasons:

- `!!` is `O(n)` operation for a list, thus making indexing into the kernel ridiculously slow. And because convolution is `O(m*n*k^2)` complexity already, where `m` and `n` are image dimensions and `k` is the kernel side the actual implementation is of `O(m*n*k^4)` complexity. That is forgoing other performance limitations of lists like boxed elements and cache unfriendliness.
- blur function is applied to an image that has an alpha channel, which is rightfully ignored, but for some reason it is just discarded and set to `255`. It is best to either drop it completely before supplying the image to blur function, or use the transparency value from the original image.
- Gaussian convolution is separable, so instead of applying a 5x5 kernel it is faster to apply `1x5` kernel onto the rows and then 5x1 to the columns. This approach reduces complexity to `O(m*n*k)`
- Convolution can be implemented much faster in general, with help of various optimizations such as fast border resolution with unsafe internal indexing, parallelization etc. All of which are pretty hard to get right, that's why it is better to use a library that provides such functionality.
- Gaussian blur kernel values that were used are designed for 8bit channels, but you are using them as floating point values. The point of 8bit in the old days was to make it run as fast as possible on old hardware because floating point numbers were slow. That's why all those tutorials online use such crappy kernels. Using a mix of `Word8` and `Double` incorrectly like it's done in the question results in a much worse quality for the filter than it really has to be. In other words you get an error due to bad values in the filter and then that error is further amplified during summation, because rounding should happen after summing the floating point values, not before.
- Another very common mistake is that [the filter is applied to the non-linear sRGB color space](https://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/linear-gamma-blur-normal-blend.html), which is most likely the color space the source image is encoded in. [It requires an inverse gamma correction first](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/6070/does-a-gaussian-blur-based-bloom-glow-shader-require-gamma-correction-any-other)
- Padding with zeros results in an image that has this white frame and of course working with slightly bigger image adds a bit of overhead.

`JuicyPixels` is a great package for encoding/decoding images, but it is definitely not suitable for more complex image processing tasks. What you need is either an actual image processing library or an array manipulation library that has already a convolution algorithm implemented. I have a library [`HIP`](https://github.com/lehins/hip) that is designed precisely for this sort of stuff, but it is undergoing a major rewrite, so I will provide an answer with an array library [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv) and [`massiv-io`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv) which actually use `JuicyPixels` underneath for reading/writing images.

Here is the fast and accurate way to do gaussian blur:

```hs
import Data.Massiv.Array as A
import Data.Massiv.Array.Unsafe (makeUnsafeConvolutionStencil)
import Data.Massiv.Array.IO as A

blurImageF :: (ColorModel cs Float) => Image S cs Float -> Image S cs Float
blurImageF = computeAs S . applyStencil padding blurStencil5x1f
           . computeAs S . applyStencil padding blurStencil1x5f
  where
    padding = noPadding -- decides what happens at the border
{-# INLINE blurImageF #-}

blurStencil1x5f :: (Floating e, ColorModel cs e) => Stencil Ix2 (Pixel cs e) (Pixel cs e)
blurStencil1x5f = makeUnsafeConvolutionStencil (Sz2 1 5) (0 :. 2) stencil
  where
    stencil f = f (0 :. -2) 0.03467403390152031 .
                f (0 :. -1) 0.23896796340399287 .
                f (0 :.  0) 0.45271600538897480 .
                f (0 :.  1) 0.23896796340399287 .
                f (0 :.  2) 0.03467403390152031
    {-# INLINE stencil #-}
{-# INLINE blurStencil1x5f #-}

blurStencil5x1f :: (Floating e, ColorModel cs e) => Stencil Ix2 (Pixel cs e) (Pixel cs e)
blurStencil5x1f = makeUnsafeConvolutionStencil (Sz2 5 1) (2 :. 0) stencil
  where
    stencil f = f (-2 :. 0) 0.03467403390152031 .
                f (-1 :. 0) 0.23896796340399287 .
                f ( 0 :. 0) 0.45271600538897480 .
                f ( 1 :. 0) 0.23896796340399287 .
                f ( 2 :. 0) 0.03467403390152031
    {-# INLINE stencil #-}
{-# INLINE blurStencil5x1f #-}
```

Values in the kernel were computed using very accurate integral approximation and optimal standard deviation for the kernel size of `σ=5/6`

In order to see this in action we first read the image, which is automatically converted to *linear* sRGB colorspace with `Float` precision (FYI the original image that was supplied in the question was in `Y'CbCr` color space, not `sRGB` with alpha channel) Then we apply the blur to it and concat together with cropped original (applying convolution without padding reduces the size). After which we convert the constructed image to `Y'CbCr` color space and write it to JPEG file:

```hs
λ> img <- readImageAuto "4ZYKa.jpg" :: IO (Image S (SRGB 'Linear) Float)
λ> let imgBlurred = blurImageF img
λ> displayImage imgBlurred -- this will open the blurred image with default viewer
λ> imgCropped <- extractM (2 :. 2) (size imgBlurred) img
λ> imgBoth <- appendM 1 imgCropped imgBlurred
λ> let out = convertPixel <$> imgBoth :: Image DL (Y'CbCr SRGB) Word8
λ> writeImage "out.jpg" out
```

Note that this will be quite a bit slower in GHCi. It needs to be compiled with `-O2 -threaded -with-rtsopts=-N` flags to get the optimal performance.

[image]