# Sharpening doesn't work - How to properly do math on Pixel8(Word8) integer values? - Convolution Image Processing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, image-processing, filter, types, pixel

I'm trying to make sharpness filter in Haskell using JuicyPixels. And I've made same Gaussian blur function and it works fine, but that one doesn't. These `(Int, Int, Int)` tuples are my workaround for storing negative pixel values. `T` means tuples there in names.

```
pxMultNumT :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Double -> (Int, Int, Int)
pxMultNumT (r, g, b) q =  (m r, m g, m b)
  where m p = floor $ fromIntegral p * q

pxPlusT :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
pxPlusT (r1, g1, b1) (r2, g2, b2) = (r1 + r2, g1 + g2, b1 + b2)

fromPixelT :: PixelRGBA8 -> (Int, Int, Int)
fromPixelT (PixelRGBA8 r g b a) = (convert r, convert g, convert b)

toPixelT :: (Int, Int, Int) -> PixelRGBA8 
toPixelT (r,g,b) = PixelRGBA8 (fromInteger $ toInteger r) (fromInteger $ toInteger g) (fromInteger $ toInteger b) 255

sharpen :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8 
sharpen img@Image {..} = generateImage blurrer imageWidth imageHeight
       where blurrer x y | x >= (imageWidth - offset) || x < offset
                          || y >= (imageHeight - offset) || y < offset = whitePx
                         | otherwise = do
                let applyKernel i j p | j >= matrixLength = applyKernel (i + 1) 0 p
                                      | i >= matrixLength = toPixelT p 
                                      | otherwise = do 
                                         let outPixelT = pxMultNumT
                                                            (fromPixelT (pixelAt img (x + j - offset) (y + i - offset)))
                                                             (kernel !! i !! j)
                                         applyKernel i (j+1) (outPixelT `pxPlusT` p)
                applyKernel 0 0 (0,0,0)
             kernel = [[   0, -0.5,    0],
                       [-0.5,    3, -0.5],
                       [   0, -0.5,    0]]
             matrixLength = length kernel
             offset = matrixLength `div` 2
```

And here are input image:[image: input image] and output image:[image: output image]
So, what did I wrong here?

*Edit:* I rewrote functions like this

```
sharpen :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Image PixelRGBA8 
sharpen img@Image {..} = promoteImage $ generateImage blurrer imageWidth imageHeight
       where blurrer x y | x >= (imageWidth - offset) || x < offset
                          || y >= (imageHeight - offset) || y < offset = PixelRGB8 0 0 0
                         | otherwise = do
                let applyKernel i j p | j >= matrixLength = applyKernel (i + 1) 0 p
                                      | i >= matrixLength = normalizePixel p 
                                      | otherwise = do 
                                         let outPixel = pxMultNum
                                                          (promotePixel $ dropTransparency $ pixelAt img (x + j - offset) (y + i - offset))
                                                           (kernel !! i !! j)
                                         applyKernel i (j+1) (pxPlus outPixel p)
                applyKernel 0 0 (PixelRGBF 0 0 0)
             kernel = [[ -1, -1, -1],
                       [-1,   9, -1],
                       [ -1, -1, -1]]
             matrixLength = length kernel
             offset = matrixLength `div` 2

pxPlus :: PixelRGBF -> PixelRGBF -> PixelRGBF
pxPlus (PixelRGBF r1 g1 b1) (PixelRGBF r2 g2 b2) = PixelRGBF (r1 + r2) (g1 + g2) (b1 + b2)

pxMultNum :: PixelRGBF -> Float -> PixelRGBF 
pxMultNum (PixelRGBF r g b) q = PixelRGBF (r * q) (g * q) (b * q)

normalizePixel :: PixelRGBF -> PixelRGB8 
normalizePixel (PixelRGBF r g b) = PixelRGB8 (n r) (n g) (n b)
  where n f = floor $ 255 * f
```

and now it works!

Comment: Please properly embed images yourself, ok? Nobody likes to click on links unnecessarily.

Comment: See my answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871842/blurring-image-with-convolution-matrices-artifacts-haskell#answer-66878751 for a better approach to deal with images in such scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is to use `Double` or `Float` instead of working with integral precision per channel. You are not gaining anything but this sort of overflow problems. Scaling `[0, 255]` range to `[0.0, 1.0]` should be the first step before you start doing image processing.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871842/blurring-image-with-convolution-matrices-artifacts-haskell#answer-66878751) to your other question for more details on what you should do to improve your implementation. Here is also a proper solution to this problem as well:

```hs
import Data.Massiv.Array as A
import Data.Massiv.Array.Unsafe (makeStencil)
import Data.Massiv.Array.IO as A


sharpenImageF :: (ColorModel cs Float) => Image S cs Float -> Image S cs Float
sharpenImageF = compute . applyStencil padding sharpStencil
  where
    padding = noPadding -- decides what happens at the border
{-# INLINE sharpenImageF #-}


sharpStencil :: (Floating e, ColorModel cs e) => Stencil Ix2 (Pixel cs e) (Pixel cs e)
sharpStencil = makeStencil (Sz2 3 3) (1 :. 1) stencil
  where
    stencil f =                   (-0.5) * f (-1 :. 0)
                - 0.5 * f ( 0 :. -1) + 3 * f ( 0 :. 0) - 0.5 * f ( 0 :. 1)
                                   - 0.5 * f ( 1 :. 0)
    {-# INLINE stencil #-}
{-# INLINE sharpStencil #-}
```

```hs
λ> img <- readImageAuto "4ZYKa.jpg" :: IO (Image S (SRGB 'Linear) Float)
λ> let imgSharpened = sharpenImageF img
λ> imgCropped <- extractM (1 :. 1) (size imgSharpened) img
λ> imgBoth <- appendM 1 imgCropped imgSharpened
λ> let out = convertPixel <$> imgBoth :: Image DL (Y'CbCr SRGB) Word8
λ> writeImage "out.jpg" $ computeAs S out
```

[image]